# How to sum data.frame column values?

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, aggregate-functions

I have a data frame with several columns; some numeric and some character. **How to compute the sum of a specific column?** I’ve googled for this and I see numerous functions (`sum`, `cumsum`, `rowsum`, `rowSums`, `colSums`, `aggregate`, `apply`) but I can’t make sense of it all.

For example suppose I have a data frame `people` with the following columns

```
people <- read.table(
  text = 
    "Name Height Weight
    Mary 65     110
    John 70     200
    Jane 64     115", 
  header = TRUE
)
…
```

How do I get the sum of all the weights?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can just use `sum(people$Weight)`.

`sum` sums up a vector, and `people$Weight` retrieves the weight column from your data frame.

Note - you can get built-in help by using `?sum`, `?colSums`, etc. (by the way, `colSums` will give you the sum for each column).

Comment: when I do this I get: `[1] NA`.  I looked at the data for this column and the very last row has NA, is that why?

Comment: Yep, that's why. You can ignore the NAs if you want via `sum(people$Weight,na.rm=TRUE)` (you can read about this option in `?sum`).

Answer (score 12):

To sum values in `data.frame` you first need to extract them as a vector.

There are several way to do it:

```
# $ operatior
x <- people$Weight
x
# [1] 65 70 64
```

Or using `[, ]` similar to matrix:

```
x <- people[, 'Weight']
x
# [1] 65 70 64
```

Once you have the vector you can use any vector-to-scalar function to aggregate the result:

```
sum(people[, 'Weight'])
# [1] 199
```

If you have NA values in your data, you should specify `na.rm` parameter:

```
sum(people[, 'Weight'], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

to order after the colsum :

```
order(colSums(people),decreasing=TRUE)
```

if more than 20+ columns

```
order(colSums(people[,c(5:25)],decreasing=TRUE) ##in case of keeping the first 4 columns remaining.
```

Answer (score 3):

When you have 'NA' values in the column, then

```
sum(as.numeric(JuneData1$Account.Balance), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use tidyverse package to solve it and it would look like the following (which is more readable for me):

```
library(tidyverse)  
people %>%
summarise(sum(weight, na.rm = TRUE))
```